# JWPlayer with RTMPT fallback when using a SMIL file

Tags: jwplayer, rtmp, wowza, smil

We are using JWPlayer 5 with Wowza Media Server 3. We are streaming video files over RTMP using a SMIL file for bitrate switching. Our problem has to do with RTMPT fallback.

When we have a single file (not using SMIL) the video will fallback to RTMPT nicely.

This works:

```
jwplayer("container").setup({
modes: [
{
type: "flash",
src: "script/js/jwplayer/player.swf",
config: {
file: "mp4:BCB6B8C3-B044-5458-056280540B47F49B/BCB6B8C3-B044-5458-056280540B47F49B_400_320.m4v",
provider: "rtmp",   
streamer: "rtmp://dev.example.com:1935/vod"
}
}
]
});
```

But, when the SMIL file is introduced the fallback does not occur.

This does NOT work:

```
jwplayer("container").setup({
modes: [
{
type: "flash",
src: "script/js/jwplayer/player.swf",
config: {
file: "assets/movie/BCB6B8C3-B044-5458-056280540B47F49B/movie_rtmp.smil",
provider: "rtmp",               
"rtmp.loadbalance": "true"
}
}
]
});
```

SMIL file:

```
<smil>
<head>
<meta base='rtmp://dev.example.com:1935/vod' />
</head>
<body>
<switch>
<video src='mp4:BCB6B8C3-B044-5458-056280540B47F49B/BCB6B8C3-B044-5458-056280540B47F49B_400_320.m4v' system-bitrate='400000' width='320' />
<video src='mp4:BCB6B8C3-B044-5458-056280540B47F49B/BCB6B8C3-B044-5458-056280540B47F49B_700_480.m4v' system-bitrate='700000' width='480' />
<video src='mp4:BCB6B8C3-B044-5458-056280540B47F49B/BCB6B8C3-B044-5458-056280540B47F49B_1100_720.m4v' system-bitrate='1100000' width='720' />
<video src='mp4:BCB6B8C3-B044-5458-056280540B47F49B/BCB6B8C3-B044-5458-056280540B47F49B_1800_1280.m4v' system-bitrate='1800000' width='1280' />
</switch>
</body>
</smil>
```

PLEASE NOTE: The SMIL version DOES WORK outside of the corporate firewall. It is only inside the corporate firewall where it should switch over the RTMPT that it doesn't work.

How can we get both RTMPT fallback and SMIL bitrate switching to play nicely together?